# C/C++: When and why do we need to call SSL_do_handshake() in a TLS client-server application?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ssl, openssl

I have created a client-server application that uses TLS for communicating with each other. I have used non-blocking sockets and using the generic OpenSSL library functions for establishing TLS channel and for IO iperations, i.e. not using BIO explicitly anywhere in my application. The application is working normally without calling SSL_do_handshake() method..

I am fairly new to OpenSSL, and recently came accross SSL__do_handshake() method while browsing the documentation. I understand the action performed by the SSL_do_handshake() method. However, it is not clear under what situation do I need to call it...

As of my understanding, SSL_accept() kicks-off the TLS handshake at the first time. And calling SSL_read() and SSL_write() internally re-negotiates the TLS handshake whenever necessary.

If my above statements are correct, then, why do we need to call SSL_do_handshake() method explicitly at all?

Comment: Without actually looking at the code, I assume it's for a situation like STARTTLS in the SMTP protocol, where a TCP connection has already been established, but the connection is changed into an encrypted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SSL_do_handshake` need to be invoked when the TLS handshake should be done. When using `SSL_accept` (server) or `SSL_connect` (client) one does not need to call `SSL_do_handshake` explicitly, since it is already done internally. Similar if `SSL_do_handshake` should used there is no need to use `SSL_accept` or `SSL_connect`, just set the SSL state accordingly (i.e. client or server side).

In other words: it is just a slightly different API with a slightly different level of control. One can use it but one does not need to use it.

Comment: So, does that mean, SSL_accept() + SSL_connect() and SSL_do_handshake() are 2 ways of doing the same thing (i.e. establish a TLS channel between client and server)?

Comment: I assumed, it might be a way to force a TLS handshake between the client and server occationally under situations of long term persisting connections. Can this be a valid possibility?

Comment: @Anirban: No. SSL_do_handshake will only start or continue with the handshake if the SSL connection is in the right state. It will not cause a new handshake if the handshake is already finished. Other functions like SSL_renegotiate might set the connection in a state where a new handshake will be required and then SSL_do_handshake will do what needs to be done for this new handshake.

Comment: I would be nice if, you know, there was documentation for these things.